# How to use a non-time-based window with spark data streaming structure?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to use window on structured streaming with spark and kafka.
I use window on non-time-based data, so I get this error:

```
'Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;;\nWindow
```

Here is my code:

```py
window = Window.partitionBy("input_id").orderBy("similarity")
outputDf = inputDf\
        .crossJoin(ticketDf.withColumnRenamed("IDF", "old_IDF")) \
        .withColumn("similarity", cosine_similarity_udf(col("IDF"), col("old_IDF"))) \
        .withColumn("rank", rank().over(window)) \
        .filter(col("rank") < 10)
```

So I am looking for a tip or a reference to use window on non-time-based data...

Comment: Spark streaming is designed to work with time as one of the dimension. Normal `Window` operations are not available  as a result. On a side note, could you paint the high level picture. I am afraid we are running into https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional SQL windowing with `over()` is not supported in Spark Structured Streaming (The only windowing it supports is time-based windowing). If you Think about it, it is probably to avoid confusions. Some may falsely assume that Spark Structured Streaming can partition the whole data based on a column (it is impossible because streams are unbounded input data).

You instead can use `groupBy()`.
`groupBy()` is also a state-full operation which is impossible to implement on `append` mode, unless we include a timestamp column in the list of columns that we want to do a groupBy operation on. For example:

```
df_result = df.withWatermark("createdAt", "10 minutes" ) \
              .groupBy( F.col('Id'), window(F.col("createdAt"), self.acceptable_time_difference)) \
              .agg(F.max(F.col('createdAt')).alias('maxCreatedAt'))
```

In this example `createdAt` is a timestamp typed column. Please note that in this case, we have to call `withWatermrke` on the timestamp column beforehand, because Spark cannot store the states boundlessly.

ps: I know groupBy does not function exactly like windowing, but with a simple join or custom function with `mapGroupsWithState`, you may be able to implement the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Windows always needs time-based data, but `Spark Structured Streaming` no.

You can create `Spark Structured Streaming` with the trigger **"as_soon_as_posible"** and you can group the data by window, the group is on time.

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time

Comment: Dear @Pablo, could you please tell me which is the trigger "as_sooon_as_possible"?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the window is only based on time...

For the application I avoid avoid the use of flask. I have looked for a long time to a streaming system... and now I am using Kafka, and it rocks for my application ! :)

And I have this resource to share with you about the Unsupported Operations with the structured streaming : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations